# Merging Multiple panel dataframes on a column named differently in each dataframe hhid

Tags: python, pandas, merge, panel-data

I have a dictionary that contains 5 data frames that I need to merge using a household id (hhid) column that is named differently in each of the dataframe. I need to merge on a list of hhid's named: w1_hhid, w2_hhid, w3_hhid, w4_hhid,w5_hhid.

My dictionary of dataframes is called adults, and it has the following keys:

```
In:   adults.keys()

Out: dict_keys(['Adult_W1_Ano', 'Adult_W2_Ano', 'Adult_W3_Ano', 'Adult_W4_Ano', 'Adult_W5_Ano'])
```

Data frame within dictionary:

```
 {'Adult_W1_Ano':        w1_hhid     pid              w1_a_outcome w1_a_phase 
                 0       101012  314585  Successfully Interviewed  Phase One  
                 1       101013  314544  Successfully Interviewed  Phase One
                 2       101013  314550  Successfully Interviewed  Phase One            
                 3       101014  301454  Successfully Interviewed  Phase Two             
                 4       101014  314575    Refused/ Not Available  Phase One  
                 5       101014  314580  Successfully Interviewed  Phase One  
                 6       101014  314581  Successfully Interviewed  Phase One            
                 7       101014  314582  Successfully Interviewed  Phase One
```

My merge attempt that I am not getting right:

```
finaladult = reduce(lambda left, right: pd.merge(left, right, on=['w1_hhid', 'w2_hhid', 'w3_hhid', 'w4_hhid', 'w5_hhid']), adults).sort_values(['w1_hhid','w2_hhid', 'w3_hhid', 'w4_hhid', 'w5_hhid'])
```

I keep getting this error message:
ValueError: can not merge DataFrame with instance of type class 'str'

Comment: look at the data types for all data frames before you merge, and see if this [help](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html)

Comment: When you reduce over a dict, it passes keys to the function, not values.

Comment: Got it, thank you!